# Unable to Persist Firebase Auth in a React Web Application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Sign Up & Sign In functionality in my React web app using Firebase Auth.

There is a Sign In page:

[image]

After I signs in, I get redirected to the `Home` page, which looks like below:

[image]

**The problem**

When on the `Home` page, if I refresh the page, I get logged out and get redirected to the Sign In page. **I don't want to get logged out on page refresh. I want the auth to persist. Only when I click on the `Logout` button, I should be logged out.**

How can I achieve this?

The code snippets are as follows:

**Signin.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { updateDisplayName } from "./authSlice";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase.config";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowRightIcon } from "../assets/svg/keyboardArrowRightIcon.svg";
import visibilityIcon from "../assets/svg/visibilityIcon.svg";

const Signin = () => {
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSignin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
       const auth = getAuth();
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      const user = userCredential.user;
      dispatch(updateDisplayName(user));
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="pageContainer">
        <header>
          <p className="pageHeader">Welcome Back!</p>
        </header>
        <main>
          <form onSubmit={handleSignin}>
            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              className="emailInput"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={email}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <div className="passwordInputDiv">
              <input
                type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                value={password}
                className="passwordInput"
                placeholder="password"
                name="password"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <img
                src={visibilityIcon}
                alt="Show password"
                className="showPassword"
                onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
              />
              <Link to="/forgot-password" className="forgotPasswordLink">
                Forgot Password
              </Link>
              <div className="signInBar">
                <p className="signinText">Sign In</p>
                <button className="signInButton">
                  <ArrowRightIcon fill="#ffffff" width="34px" height="34px" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          {/* Google OAuth */}
          <Link to="/sign-up" className="registerLink">
            Sign Up
          </Link>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Signin;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAuth, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectDisplayName } from "./authSlice";

const Home = () => {
  const name = useSelector(selectDisplayName);

  const auth = getAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    signOut(auth);
    navigate("/sign-in");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>Wecome {name}</div>
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**firebase.config.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  browserLocalPersistence,
  getAuth,
  setPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Details
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `onAuthStateChanged` to achieve that. I recommended to add that code in `App.js`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

```
  import { auth } from "./firebase";

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);

  // Check if user is logged in and set user data to persist state between page reloads
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      dispatch(setUser(user));
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [dispatch]);

 return (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route
          index
          element={user ? <Navigate to="locations" /> : <Auth />}
        />
       ...other routes...
```

See my GitHub project for reference - https://github.com/mile-mijatovic/React-CRUD-App/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: No, the auth is still not persisting. My repo: https://github.com/sundaray/House-Marketplace.git